# I can't get my model to stand up straight in pose mode

Tags: armature

I'm animating a model for the first time without step-by-step instructions.  I can't get my model (R2-D2) to stand up straight in pose mode. The bones turn into a pile when I try to move them.  I think my problem would be more easily solved if someone were able to actually open my .blend file and look at it.  Is it possible to upload my file with my question? Since the Blend-Exchange method isn't working, I am now trying to make my file available through Dropbox. dropbox.com/s/y8jfkcdp1eg4a5m/R2D2-e.blend?dl=0

Comment: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links

Comment: use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: upload your model and paste the link on your question.

Comment: The bones turn into a pile when I try to move them.  I have saved one pose of the model on three legs in the pose library.  I will attach the .blend file now that I know how to do that.

Comment: When I upload the .blend file through giantcowfilms.com, this text appears: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)' in /var/www/blend-exchange/parts/database.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/blend-exchange/parts/database.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'blend-exchange', 'BLD-db-Exchange...') #1 /var/www/blend-exchange/finish/index.php(93): include('/var/www/blend-...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/blend-exchange/parts/database.php on line 3"

Comment: Since the Blend-Exchange method isn't working, I am now trying to make my file available through Dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8jfkcdp1eg4a5m/R2D2-e.blend?dl=0

Comment: @giantcowfilms it seems that you need to restart your MySql server.

Comment: You need to move the root bone, due to the IK-Constraints it might not behave as you want. It would be easier to remove IK and use drivers if necessary.

Comment: @stacker Thank you very much.  I haven't learned about drivers yet, but I removed the IK and posed the model without them.  It works great.  Thanks again for the help; I've been trying to fix this all day.